# How do I distribute keys into buckets but ensure that each bucket has at least one key?

Tags: java, md5, hashcode, modulo, bucket

I have a set of "keys" and "buckets", where num_keys > num_buckets, but they are roughly the same order of magnitude.

To give a concrete example, a "key" would be analogous to a task, and a "bucket" to a thread. I want to distribute the tasks as evenly as possible to the threads, while ensuring that no thread is idle.

For example, I would have 400 tasks, and 200 threads:

```
task1, task2, ..., task400
thread1, thread1, ... thread200
```

And I want to assign tasks somewhat uniformly to the threads:

```
thread1 -> task50, task394
thread2 -> task37, task250, task324
...
thread200 -> task20
```

These are numbers I made up, but to be clear, it's more important to me that there are no idle threads; I don't care that much about having perfect distribution.

Some other properties that are important to me:

- There is no bias toward a particular bucket.
- The same key should always be assigned to the same bucket, regardless of the number of keys. If the number of buckets change, it's OK for the assignments to change (so no need for some kind of consistent hashing scheme).
- The distribution should happen independently without external coordination.

Currently, I'm trying to do this with MD5:

```java
BigInteger numThreads = BigInteger.valueOf(200); // buckets
BigInteger currentThreadId = BigInteger.valueOf(1); 
List<Task> tasks = getGlobalTasks(); // keys
List<Task> myTasks = new ArrayList<>();

for (Task task : tasks) {
    BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(task.getId()));
    BigInteger bucketId = hash.mod(numThreads);
    if (currentThreadId.equals(bucketId)) {
      myTasks.add(task);
    }
}
```

I suspect that this method would work fine if there was a greater disparity between the number of keys and buckets. However, with this current scheme, about 35 of my threads are sitting idle because it hasn't been assigned any keys. I'm guessing that this is due to variance from the MD5 hash distribution.

So the question is, is there any way to restructure this code to ensure that each bucket/thread will receive at least one task?

**Note:** What I'm actually trying to do is assign [AWS Kinesis Shards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html) to [Apache Storm Spouts](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Concepts.html) in a way that is resilient to [resharding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-using-sdk-java-resharding.html) (which means changing the number of shards). The details of this aren't important for this question though.

Here is an example of the code sample from above that compiles/runs:

```java
  public static void main(String [] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    BigInteger numBuckets= BigInteger.valueOf(20); // buckets
    int numTasks = 40;

    List<BigInteger> tasks = new ArrayList<>(); // keys
    for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
      tasks.add(BigInteger.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 5000)));
    }

    Map<BigInteger, List<BigInteger>> bucketToTasks = new HashMap<>();
    for (BigInteger task : tasks) {
        String taskStr = task.toString();
        BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(taskStr.getBytes()));
        BigInteger bucketId = hash.mod(numBuckets);
        if (!bucketToTasks.containsKey(bucketId)) {
          bucketToTasks.put(bucketId, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        bucketToTasks.get(bucketId).add(task);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numBuckets.intValue(); i++){
      System.out.println("Bucket: " + i + ", Tasks: " + bucketToTasks.get(BigInteger.valueOf(i)));
    }
  }
```

And the output:

```
Bucket: 0, Tasks: [2459, 2922]
Bucket: 1, Tasks: [21]
Bucket: 2, Tasks: [453]
Bucket: 3, Tasks: [494]
Bucket: 4, Tasks: null
Bucket: 5, Tasks: [1557, 2355]
Bucket: 6, Tasks: [4145, 1693]
Bucket: 7, Tasks: null
Bucket: 8, Tasks: null
Bucket: 9, Tasks: [1016, 4556]
Bucket: 10, Tasks: [3739]
Bucket: 11, Tasks: [4644, 3295]
Bucket: 12, Tasks: [2773, 3983, 2724]
Bucket: 13, Tasks: [1663]
Bucket: 14, Tasks: [2593, 2593, 1457, 3023, 1817, 4353, 4196]
Bucket: 15, Tasks: [2258, 802, 1530]
Bucket: 16, Tasks: [1882, 4765, 1969]
Bucket: 17, Tasks: [4882, 3030, 3429]
Bucket: 18, Tasks: [1666, 4377, 1714, 4109]
Bucket: 19, Tasks: [819, 7]
```

As you can see, some buckets are completely empty.

Comment: Why do you not fill the tasks in sequence into the buckets? The `N`th task will go to the bucket `N % numBuckets`. So they fill the buckets `1` to `X` and the next new tasks will start filling from bucket `1` again.

Comment: In my particular case, the number of tasks sometimes change over time. If the number of tasks change, existing tasks might not be assigned to the bucket they were previously in, I think (assuming the tasks are sorted by something, if a task is removed then all subsequent tasks will be assigned to bucket i - 1). My threads run in different machines and so don't have access to shared memory.

Comment: You have a requirement which is unable to solve. You say that they keys should be assigned always to the same bucket but also keys should be assigned to a different bucket when the bucket is free. Either you let them move or you don't, which one is it?

Comment: Ah, I meant that I want each bucket to have at least one key in the _original_ assignment. If a key is removed such that the bucket containing it becomes empty, it is not necessary to migrate keys to that bucket. If so many keys are removed that num_keys < num_buckets, then obviously there will be empty buckets.

Comment: I'm talking about keys where the *original* assignment is the same. When you have two keys which goes to bucket `5` and you don't want to change that, how can they be moved to a different bucket which is empty? That's an impossible requirement. Either you keep the assignment fixed or you change them. You have to choose: do you want to keep the original assignment of the keys to their buckets as final or do you want to assign keys to different buckets (from their original assignment) depending on circumstances (like an empty bucket)? These requirements are in conflict to each other.

Comment: The keys in the original assignment comes from the bucketing scheme. In my case the bucketing scheme uses MD5 hash and modulo. I'm wondering if there exists an "original assignment" bucketing scheme that ensures every bucket has at least one key without having to move anything, perhaps with some tradeoff. Is it impossible? I don't know.

Comment: That is not possible without looking at the current fill state of the buckets you have. If you can look at the fill state of each bucket then you can adjust the key calculation to return a key first for an empty bucket. But then the key calculation depends on the status of the buckets. The question is if you want to look at the states of the buckets and adjust the key calculation or not. It sounds like you **don't** want that but also **do** want that at the same time, which makes it impossible.